# Oracle change notification - how to prepare query for registration?

Tags: oracle, odp.net, change-notification

I cant register a query to satisfy my conditions.
I have 2 applications running from 2 computers.
Following query is registered by each application:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE cast(SOME_COLUMN/1000 as int)=@APP_NUMBER
```

Each application set own @APP_NUMBER in registered query.
The problem is when I add new row with SOME_COLUMN/1000 set to 1 only first application should be notify. But both are.
Thx for any help

Comment: Are you using a bind variable for APP_NUMBER? From the point of view Oracle, I think that would mean the queries are identical (no parse needed). Try using a static value there instead of a bind variable just to prove that it is what is going on.

Comment: It is some number pass before query execute

Comment: Are you using a bind variable (OracleParameter) or just appending the number to the end of the SQL statement?

Comment: I append number to end sql statement when prepare query in c #